# How to set mapping for indexes but excluding some of them in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a mapping that I want to set in some indexes like below,

```
country_city_*
country_street_*
country_cars_*
```

But I don't want to set that mapping the that kinds of type like

```
 county_person_*
 country_city_errors
```

I have tried to use this below,

```
PUT /contry_*, -contry_person_*, -country_*_errors/_mapping
{
    //some mappings in json
}
```

But I get this error

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "not_x_content_exception",
        "reason" : "Compressor detection can only be called on some xcontent bytes or compressed xcontent bytes"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "not_x_content_exception",
    "reason" : "Compressor detection can only be called on some xcontent bytes or compressed xcontent bytes"
  },
  "status" : 500
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `compressor detection ...` error is raised when you have disallowed whitespace in your request URI.

[Multiple targets](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html#put-mapping-api-multi-ex) are indeed allowed but make sure you include the `allow_no_indices` option and of course properly structure your wildcards:

```
PUT /contry_*,*-contry_person_*,*-country_*_errors/_mapping?allow_no_indices=true
{
  "properties": {
    "someTextField": {
      "type": "text"
    }
  }
}
```

BTW, the standard practice of creating mappings for indices that **haven't been created yet** is called [index templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-templates.html). In your particular case you could say:

```
PUT _index_template/country_template
{
  "index_patterns": [
    "contry_*",
    "*-contry_person_*",
    "*-country_*_errors"     <-- any patterns you like but index names should NOT start with a hyphen
  ],
  "template": {
    "mappings": {
      "properties": {
        "someTextField": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "createdAt": {
          "type": "date"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you then ingest a new document into a new index on-the-fly:

```
POST contry_abc/_doc
{ "someTextField": "abc" }
```

the proper mapping will have been set:

```
GET contry_abc/_mapping
```

Comment: Your answer is correct. Thanks for answering. If you like the question feel free to upvote :)